# Is there a way to see source file in splunk search.?

Tags: splunk

As part of our work, we need to index our client's configuration files into splunk and prepare reports on them for them. We need to reports in splunk similar to their existing reporting framework, we need to allow users to view specific configuration files and they might compare two different files or perform diff etc.

I would like to see if there is a way to view the whole file in pop up window in splunk search.? If it is not already defined, could you please provide me the way to achieve it.?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you use, there is a down arrow by each log entry. Click that and then click "Show Source". you can view the source that way.

or, you can change the query so that source="path/to/source.log" to see all the log entries from that source file.